# Scrapy - How to store the local path of a downloaded image?

Tags: python, image, scrapy

My scraper is working well, it downloads images and registers items in database, but I also want their local paths to be saved into my MySQL database and I don't know how to proceed.

I've read this in the doc :

> When the images are downloaded another field (images) will be
>   populated with the results.

With the code below, the path isn't saved and I've got this error:

```
return self._values[key]
    exceptions.KeyError: 'images'
```

Here are extracts of my code:

**items.py:**

```
image_urls = Field()
images = Field()
```

**my_spider.py:**

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from project.items import ArtistItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):

    name = 'XXX'
    allowed_domains = ['XXX']
    start_urls = [
        "XXX",
        "XXX"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        x = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        artist = ArtistItem()
        artist['url'] = response.url
        artist['name'] = x.select("//h1/text()").extract()
        artist['city'] = x.select("//span[@class='profile_location']/text()").extract()
        artist['style'] = x.select("//span[@class='profile_genre']/text()").extract()
        image_urls = x.select('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/a/img/@src').extract()
        artist['image_urls'] = ["http:" + x for x in image_urls]

        return artist
```

**pipelines.py:**

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
import sys


class ProjectPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='XXX', passwd='XXX', db='XXX', charset='utf8',
                             use_unicode=True)

        self.c = db.cursor()
        self.c.connection.autocommit(True)


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.c.execute("""INSERT INTO artist (name, city, style, image_url)
                        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""",
                           (item['name'][0],
                            item['city'][0],
                            item['style'][0],
                            item['images'][0]['path'],
                           ))

        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
            sys.exit(1)

        return item
```

What I'm missing in the parse() function ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't seem to be handling field images anywhere (which is holding the results).

Comment: You're right, but I don't know how to handle it: artist['images'] = ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha. I had a read of the [scrapy documentation on downloading images](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/images.html?highlight=images#custom-images-pipeline-example) and also [the source file for images.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/images.py).

In theory what you're doing should work, but it may well be easier to create a custom Images Pipeline that explicitly appends the saved image path to each item. Handily enough, [the example given does just that](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/images.html?highlight=images). :)

Once you've implemented that, then modify process_item in your ProjectPipeline as follows:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    try:
        self.c.execute("""INSERT INTO artist (name, city, style, image_url)
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""",
                       (item['name'][0],
                        item['city'][0],
                        item['style'][0],
                        item['image_paths'],
                       ))

    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
        sys.exit(1)

    return item
```

Just remember to update your settings.py file to refer to your custom Images Pipeline file and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you, but I've got the same kind of error: `return self._values[key]
 exceptions.KeyError: 'images_urls'`. Plus, I want to store the local path of the downloaded file (I've edited my question to clarify this point).

Comment: If you pass a fixed string to the insert statement, does the pipeline work? It will be easier to check this if you post all of your spider and pipelines code.

Comment: If I pass a fixed string, the pipeline is working well. I've updated my question to put the entire code.

Comment: Thanks again for your time @Talvalin, editing settings.py made me realize I hadn't set the pipelines classes in ITEM_PIPELINES array in the right order. So the ProjectPipeline which was doing the insertion in db was running before the ImagesPipeline... The custom pipeline solution is working well too...

Answer (score 1):

Priority of your components in the ITEM_PIPELINES setting is important in order to save images to your DB.

For example if you are using MongoDB to store the Items. Here is how you should have priorities of your pipeline components in your settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline':1,
    'yourscrapyproject.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline':100}
```

The above setting will ensure that Images are processed and item['image'] is populated before the control moves to MongoDBPipeline for storing the image information.

You can read more about setting priority in ITEM_PIPELINES in the last section of this doc: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

Took me hours to figure this out so making a note here so that its helpful for others facing the same issue.